# Generic "Lefty" single-sided fork and hub?

Tags: fork, lefty-fork

Is Cannondale's Lefty the only half/mono/single fork?

Comment: No. USE made a single sided fork and 8-freight use single sided front and rear wheels and there are others but mostly niche. Cannondale's version is the best known.

Comment: @JoeK that's totally an answer -could you please copy-paste it down below?

Answer (score 4):

No. USE made a single sided fork and 8-freight use single sided front and rear wheels and there are others but mostly niche. Cannondale's version is the best known

The first single sided fork I became aware of was used by the presenter of “What the Romans Did For Us”, Adam Hart-Davis. I’d love to know what his bike was.